# What's the shortcut key for snapping pie menu in blender 2.8

Tags: shortcut, snapping, pie-menu

Just a quick question, what is the shortcut key for snapping in pie menus? If there is none, how to create one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean this menu:

[image: screenshot]

the shortcut is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

<sub>And for the other pie menus see [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/153195/what-are-the-shortcuts-for-the-pie-menus/153196#153196).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

In Blender 2.8 Beta, if you deselect the Pie Menu: UI Pie Menu Official addon and select the Pie Menu: 3D Viewport Pie Menus addon, the shortcut is 'Ctrl Shift Tab'.

[image]