# What are the shortcuts for the pie menus?

Tags: interface

The shortcuts for the pie menus aren't shown in any tooltip, so I can never remember them. What are they?

Answer (score 23):

#### Mode

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>

[image: screenshot]

#### Proportional Editing Falloff

<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

[image: screenshot]

#### Snapping

This one is not a pie menu, but its shortcut seems to be missing from the tooltip as well, so I included it in the list:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>

[image: screenshot]

#### Snap

<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

[image: screenshot]

#### Pivot Point

<kbd>.</kbd>

[image: screenshot]

#### Transform Orientation

<kbd>,</kbd>

[image: screenshot]

#### Shading

<kbd>Z</kbd>

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This should be the first page of the Blender manual +1

Answer (score 7):

**`** <-

The backtick opens the ***`Snap To View`*** *Pie Menu*

[image]

Comment: The backtick `opens  the viewport align pie menu, eg Top -> Numpad 7

Comment: `SHIFT+Spacebar` for tool menu is yet another one.

Comment: on an azerty keyboard it's "ù".  
it will be cool one day blender takes in charge other keyboards. I mean precisely...but maybe it's quite impossible when a key doesn't exist in English... or a table of conversion? no idea in fact how to program this. nothing is simple in this world. between languages, OS ...

Answer (score 1):

*View* pie menu opens up with <kbd>ö</kbd> on a German keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>A</kbd> on **Sculpt Mode** brings **Masking** related shortcuts.

[image: screenshot of blender UI]