# are there any hot keys for changing through viewport mode like solid, render and wireframe

Tags: 3d-view

I just wish to know if there are any hotkeys for viewport as it is a little slow to do it with a mouse, I would appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: What do you mean by "through viewport"?

Comment: sorry i meant like solid mode, render mode etc

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/153195

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Z</kbd> will bring this menu:

[image]

And <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> will toggle from the last selected solid view (solid, material preview or rendered) and wireframe.

Comment: thanks for the answer

Comment: You should accept the answer if it corresponds to your question: that helps the site to recognize useful questions/answers.

Comment: Worth pointing out that the numbers alongside each popup option can be used to select that option without using the mouse - so Z followed by 4 for Wireframe, Z followed by 6 for Solid, etc.

Comment: @RichSedman, yes but more or less easy to use depending on the keyboard you have (either needs to use shift or far from z).

Comment: Agreed, just thought to make it clear that don’t need to use the mouse since that was the original question. No worries.