# 2.93 - What's the shortcut key for the Vertex, edge, face, pie menu?

Tags: pie-menu

What's the shortcut key for the Vertex, edge, face, pie menu? (not the 1,2,3 keys)

Comment: There isn't one to my knowledge. See [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/153195/what-are-the-shortcuts-for-the-pie-menus) answer for all the available pie menu shortcuts

Comment: PMP was indeed the addon, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't one in the built in pie menus. [Viewport Pie Menus](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.93/addons/interface/viewport_pies.html) lists all of the available Pie menus.

There are third party add-ons, such as [Pie Menus Plus](https://razed.gumroad.com/l/piesplus), that add additional pie menus, including the one you're looking for. You have to check the documentation for the particular add-on to see what keys it maps.